# How to stop uwsgi when no pidfile in config?

Tags: uwsgi

I've just installed `uwsgi` by `pip install uwsgi` in a virtual env.
In "ini" file I used:

```
socket = 127.0.0.1:3000
# no pidfile option
```

And run `uwsgi --ini config.ini`

But how to stop this instance of uwsgi?
`uwsgi --stop ...` wants a pid file. I can't use an address:

```
open("127.0.0.1:3000"): No such file or directory [core/io.c line 505]
```

And if killing - uwsgi just respawns itself.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
ps ax | grep uwsgi
15005 pts/4    S      0:00 /ve/path/bin/uwsgi --ini config.ini
15006 pts/4    S      0:00 /ve/path/bin/uwsgi --ini config.ini
15007 pts/4    S      0:00 /ve/path/bin/uwsgi --ini config.ini

killall -s INT /ve/path/bin/uwsgi
```

Comment: If you don't have `killall`, you can also do `sudo pkill -f uwsgi -9`

Answer (score 4):

It is a known feature that you cannot terminate uwsgi with just kill. The second bullet of: http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ThingsToKnow.html

> Til uWSGI 2.1, by default, sending the SIGTERM signal to uWSGI means “brutally reload the stack” while the convention is to shut an application down on SIGTERM. To shutdown uWSGI use SIGINT or SIGQUIT instead. If you absolutely can not live with uWSGI being so disrespectful towards SIGTERM, by all means enable the die-on-term option. Fortunately, this bad choice has been fixed in uWSGI 2.1

Answer (score 2):

Similar to the top one answer, in Ubuntu or Debian you can simply do`sudo killall -9 uwsgi`. Though I do want to know if uwsgi gives a way to stop itself.

Answer (score 0):

In my own case, uwsgi was started by another process. Sergey's answer helped me to find which process it was but couldn't kill it. Supervisorctl was what worked for me.

```
sudo supervisorctl stop uwsgi
```